# finding children in php simplexml xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am running an xpath query on an xml stream and retreiving a set of data. In that i need to find the tag name. But im not able to find the way to retrieve the tag name. The xml stream is

```
<Condition> 
          <Normal dataItemId="Xovertemp-06" timestamp="2011-09-02T03:35:34.535703Z" name="Xovertemp" sequence="24544" type="TEMPERATURE"/> 
          <Normal dataItemId="Xservo-06" timestamp="2011-09-02T03:35:34.535765Z" name="Xservo" sequence="24545" type="LOAD"/> 
          <Normal dataItemId="Xtravel-06" timestamp="2011-09-02T03:35:34.535639Z" name="Xtravel" sequence="24543" type="POSITION"/> 
</Condition>
```

I am trying to parse this as

```
Temperature = Normal
Load - Normal
```

So what i did is

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("//n:Condition")->children("n") as $child) {
    echo $child["type"] . "="  . $child->getName();
}
```

I am getting the followin error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\DataDumper\datadumper\test.php on line 53
```

Now i know this has got something to do with the way i query the xpath or something and i tried various combination such as adding an * slash to the query but the same error every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you used namespace notaion in the first place(the sample xml is not namespaced)

In your xpath, you need to select all `condition/normal` tags, not the `condition` tag as you were doing...
Also, `xpath()` returns a list, so `foreach` over it. You don't need to access it as children, unless you want to parse the children of `$child`. There it would make sense, and it would work as expected.

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("/Condition/Normal") as $child) {
    echo $child["type"] . "="  . $child->getName()."<br/>";
}
```

outputs

```
TEMPERATURE=Normal
LOAD=Normal
POSITION=Normal
```

Comment: I was under the impression the OP did not know the tag names of the child elements in which case, this would only work for `<Normal>` children

Comment: The actual xml has namespace thats why i added it here. Also i cant do /condition/Normal as normal is not static it could change, but i changed it to /condition/* and it works! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returning an array and not a `SimpleXMLElement`. I'm also not sure about the namespace support in the XPath query however I'm sure you can fiddle with that to work it out. In any case, I see no `n` namespace in your XML.

The answer really depends on how many elements you expect to match your XPath query. If only one, try

```
$conditions = $xml->xpath('//Condition');
if (count($conditions) == 0) {
    throw new Exception('No conditions found');
}
$condition = $conditions[0];
foreach ($condition->children() as $child) {
    printf('%s = %s', (string) $child['type'], $child->getName());
}
```